# How to use sapply - switch logic

Tags: r, switch-statement, sapply

I have data frame that I am using for a small educational project.

```
                            EVTYPE PROPDMG PROPDMGEXP CROPDMG CROPDMGEXP 
192527 URBAN/SMALL STREAM FLOODING     0.0          5       0            
192938                  HEAVY SNOW     1.7          5       0            
193995                        HAIL    30.0          5      25          M 
194223          THUNDERSTORM WINDS     0.1          5       0            
195672          THUNDERSTORM WINDS     0.0          5       0            
198497          THUNDERSTORM WINDS    10.0          5       0
```

My objective is to create a new column named PropAmtDmg and takes the following form.
If PROPDMGEXP = "5" then 5 * PROPDMG

```
t1$PropAmtDmg <- ifelse(t1$PROPDMGEXP == "7", t1$PROPDMG * 7,
                        ifelse(t1$PROPDMGEXP == "5", t1$PROPDMG * 5,
                               0))
```

I might of more cases than just two that I mentioned.
I would like to do this in `sapply`.

Comment: if you find an answer acceptable, please remember to accept it

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the use of `data.table` for this task. `data.table` is a package that enhances data frames inherent in R. It is **very fast**. The benefit of this is there is not constant recopying of data so that if your data is large, this is memory efficient. Let's assume that your data frame is called `dfr`:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(123) #set the seed so this can be replicated
dtb = data.table(PROPDMGEXP = sample(1:10, 10), PROPDMG = sample(1:10,10)) #sample data.table
dtb[(PROPDMGEXP %in% c(5,7)),rslt:=PROPDMG*PROPDMGEXP]
```

You are done. Here is the result:

```
    PROPDMGEXP PROPDMG rslt
 1:          3      10   NA
 2:          8       5   NA
 3:          4       6   NA
 4:          7       9   63
 5:          6       1   NA
 6:          1       7   NA
 7:         10       8   NA
 8:          9       4   NA
 9:          2       3   NA
10:          5       2   10
```

Note: if you want to make all the other entries 0 you can do this instead:

```
dtb[,rslt:=0][(PROPDMGEXP %in% c(5,7)),rslt:=PROPDMG*PROPDMGEXP]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate all conditions in a unique one like this :

```
transform(t1,PropAmtDmg=ifelse(PROPDMGEXP %in% c(5,7),PROPDMG*PROPDMGEXP,0))
```